# SPContext.Current is null

Tags: spcontext

I am making a call to a Web service on the initial load of the page through an Angular JS Service. The Web service calls a DLL where I am accessing `SPContext.Current`. If I am allowing the application to run without debugging, the object comes up as null.

Next what I did was I did a quick watch on `SPContext.Current`, and sure enough it came up null. But to my surprise when I did a quick watch on it again, the value was there. This was during the same debugging session.

Does anyone have any idea why the value appears when I am doing a second quick watch on `SPContext.Current`.

Comment: Is this helpful http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/18430/is-spcontext-current-supposed-to-be-null-in-custom-wcf-service?rq=1

Comment: I had tried this earlier by calling the web service explicitly. But it didn't help.

Comment: I had a similar issue with WCF service hosted in SP 2010. I eventualy ended up opening SPWeb in service ctor and disposing the it after call, i.e. I didn't use SPContext at all. This didn't introduce performance issues.

Comment: SPContext relies on a valid HTTPContext, if that helps.